# TEE Chart version 5 download

Tags: teechart

I have been trying to recreate a customer's environment, they use Crystal Reports and TeeChart v5 to create reports and view data.
Is it possible to download the tee chart v5 activex control?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you hold a TeeChart Pro v5 ActiveX license. You can use your licensing information [here](http://www.steema.com/clientaccess) to download the product. Otherwise please contact our Sales Dept at [sales at steema dot com](http://mailto%3asales@steema.com) for available options.